# Execute Action on UI Thread Synchronously in WinRT

Tags: windows-runtime

I'm developing some corss platform library, and need to execute a action on the UI thread.
Although I know there is a method Dispatcher.RunAsync can execute the action on UI thread, but it is async, and I can't use await/async feature becuase the code is corss platform and I don't want the library is bound to the await/async feature of .net 4.5.

Is there any way to execute the action on UI thread synchronously?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A cross-platform library should not depend on a particular UI (e.g., `Dispatcher` or `CoreDispatcher`). There's a type that represents an abstract "context": `SynchronizationContext`; I wrote an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx) on the subject a while back.

If it is possible for your library to capture the UI context before it needs to use it, then you can capture `SynchronizationContext.Current` and later use `Send` to execute some code on the original context synchronously.

Comment: Thank you very much! This article gives me much of the knowledge. The portable class library should not depends on dispatcher, this is true. and this is why I need to exectue on UI thread sync, because in the protable class lib, I define an interface, which has a method called "ExecuteOnUIThread" which accept an Func<T,T1> and return T1, as this is portable class lib, so I can't defien ExecuteOnUIThreadAsync, and when I implement this inferface on different platform, for exampe wpf, monodroid, it is ok. but for winRT, I can't. I try to use wait, but it is sometime deadlock.

Comment: Sorry, Send is not available in WinRT.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @DRAirey1: The best option is to not get into this scenario in the first place: structure your library so that it acts as a service for the UI. Ideally, a library should not even be aware that there *is* a UI.

Comment: Stephen, I agree with your statement in general, however, as other posters have observed, this makes trivial tasks into complex engineering feats.  You can accomplish the same thing with an 'await' on the async version, but the larger problem is deadlocks.  I was able to solve my problem, which involved loading up Bitmap streams from async calls and then creating BitmapImages from them, but it's not code I would want to revisit again.

Comment: @DRAirey1: I disagree that this is a complex engineering feat. Separating logic from UI results in much cleaner code with higher separation of concerns. `Bitmap` is an awkward case, because it's something that's tied to the UI that *shouldn't* be.

Answer (score 1):

If you execute it from the UI thread - there is no way to do it. From a background thread you might do it for example using an AutoResetEvent that you wait for after calling RunAsync and setting it from the RunAsync callback.

Comment: Thank you. If use AutoResetEvent, is it similar to Task.Wait()? If this is true, maybe it will cause dead lock.

Comment: Yes, it might, though since you would run it from the background thread and the dispatcher is on a UI thread - it reduces the risk a little bit. Anyways though, hey, I don't recommend it. :)